# Command to send swap to memory again

Tags: linux, memory, swap

Is there a way to send the memory swapped, back again to the principal memory?

**EDIT:** I had a process that I ran and eated all memory, so now, each time I use another app, it has something in swap, so it takes time to reload to memory. Now the consuming memory process has stopped, I want to **force** to have  all the things in memory again. So I will wait only one time to have the things that are in swap to memory again, and not each time that I reuse an opened app.

Comment: Happens automatically when needed, without your process ever knowing it happened.

Comment: You mean from outside the OS? I don't know for sure but I highly doubt it...

Comment: If you really want to force it to empty the swap file there's always [`swapoff`](http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Swapoff_Performance)

Comment: If you know that particular bit of memory's been swapped out, then try to read from it - the OS will be forced to swap it back in, since it won't "read" the byte you've requested from the ondisk cache.

Comment: @awoodland can I do swapoff and then swapon to empty swap to memory? (Make it an answer and I mark it as accepted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly; moreover, usually you don't want to, as often what is swapped is the part that is no longer needed (initialization code).  The only way to force the issue is to ask the kernel to disable the swap area, and even that is not immediate.

Comment: would you please ellaborate a little more? are you referring to swapoff/swapon?

Comment: Yes, that's `swapoff`.  `swapoff` is really just a suggestion, though; no guarantees are made as to when swap will actually be emptied and released.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel will automatically and transparently swap that data back into RAM when it's required.

You can avoid getting swapped out using `mlock()` or `mlockall()`, but you probably shouldn't do that. If your app ends up getting swapped out it might be using too much memory, or there could be too little memory in the machine, or too many running processes. None of those problems will be improved by your app using `mlock()`.

Comment: I suppose you could attach gdb and manually call mlockall(() from gdb.